# Text is too close to the edge of col or box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, padding

Does any of you know how to add padding to the text?  Here is the image.
[image]

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body --> 
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center flex-column justify-content-center bg-dark">
    <h2 class="mb-0 text-white">Za sve vremenske prilike</h2>
    <br>
    <p class="mb-0 text-white">Grijanje i Hlađenje</p>
    <p class="mb-0 text-white">Zgrada je opremljena najsavremenijom tehnologijom.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 order-first order-md-last">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg" class="w-100 h-100">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily fixable with the padding property being applied to the div that contains the text elements, but one side effect that you may not like is that the box can get bigger in order to apply the space around the inner text elements
this too can be easily fixed by telling your css file that:
box-sizing: border-box
I'm assuming that you're using tailwind and in tailwind those properties are set like the following:
p-[2,4,...]
box-border

in short:

```
<div class="col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center flex-column justify-content-center bg-dark box-border p-4">
<h2 class="mb-0 text-white">Za sve vremenske prilike</h2>
<br>
<p class="mb-0 text-white">Grijanje i Hlađenje</p>
<p class="mb-0 text-white">Zgrada je opremljena najsavremenijom tehnologijom.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you rock, the perfect answer, and the box are much better.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a padding class to the `<div>` that contains text such as `p-5`

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body --> 
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center flex-column justify-content-center bg-dark p-5">
    <h2 class="mb-0 text-white">Za sve vremenske prilike</h2>
    <br>
    <p class="mb-0 text-white">Grijanje i Hlađenje</p>
    <p class="mb-0 text-white">Zgrada je opremljena najsavremenijom tehnologijom.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 order-first order-md-last">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg" class="w-100 h-100">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a `<div>` tag for the `<p>` elements so for example:

```
<div class="example">
    <p class="mb-0 text-white">Grijanje i Hlađenje</p>
    <p class="mb-0 text-white">Zgrada je opremljena najsavremenijom tehnologijom.</p>
</div>
```

Inside your CSS folder you would want to do this:

```
div.example p {
padding: 5px 0px 0px 5px; /* top, right, bottom, left */ /* you can also use % and auto aswell as vh cm in */
text-align: center; /* left, center, right */
/* justify-content: left; | left, center, right */
/* float:left;| left, right */
}
```

You could also do:

```
div.example p {
padding-left: 5px; /* you can also use % and auto aswell as vh cm in */
padding-top: 5px; /* you can also use % and auto aswell as vh cm in */
padding-bottom: 0px; /* you can also use % and auto aswell as vh cm in */
padding-right: 0px; /* you can also use % and auto aswell as vh cm in */
}
```

There is also `margin` that you could use for padding:

```
div.example p {
margin-top: 5px; /* you can also use % and auto aswell as vh cm in */
margin-left: 5px; /* you can also use % and auto aswell as vh cm in */
margin-right: 0px; /* you can also use % and auto aswell as vh cm in */
margin-bottom: 0px; /* you can also use % and auto aswell as vh cm in */
}
```

Lastly you could just not create a div and just do:

```
p.text-padding {
padding: check above;
color: #ffffff; /* text color */
float: where you want;
text-decoration: none; /* underline */
}
```

and your HTML must be like this:

```
 <p class="mb-0 text-white text-padding">Grijanje i Hlađenje</p>
 <p class="mb-0 text-white text-padding">Zgrada je opremljena najsavremenijom tehnologijom.</p> <!--- Use any css for the second one or the same --->
```

I hope this helped you understand different ways to align text and use padding

Answer (score -1):

If you're using CSS you can add the padding by padding-top
padding-right
padding-bottom
padding-left

Of you're not using CSS you can just add **br** on the line before the h2 tag

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but the guy above you gave me a solution, one more time thank you so much. I can't upvote your answer because my reputation is too low :/

Comment: its poor solution. This answer does not consider that use of the framework that is already used. Also including an h2 tag as spacer is a wrong solution for any decent programming. Thats what you have margins and padding for.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Changing your `<div>` Tags to

```
<div class="col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center flex-column justify-content-center bg-dark" style="padding: 8px;">
```

and

```
<div class="col-md-6 order-first order-md-last" style="padding: 8px;">
```

should do. Change "8px" to the space you need. If you need to add inner space on a certain side of your box only, you can use "padding-top", "padding-bottom", "padding-left" and "padding-right". If you need different spaces, you can use this: "padding: 10px 5px 12px 5px;" (top, right, bottom, left).

As an other way you could add the padding to one of the css classes; that would be the better solution regarding reuse and not mixing "class" and "style".

Comment: using a style attribute is the wrong way to solve styling issues unless you talk about HTML emails. Also, you ignore the usage of the framework. The framework has classes for padding (`p-value`).

Comment: Admittedly I didn't know bootstrap does have classes just for padding. But did you see the last paragraph of my answer? There I advised the enquierer to better use css if possible. So the solution considers different circumstances.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).